# Can ArcGIS Operations Dashboard manage routine data collection at same geographic points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatio-temporal-data, operations-dashboard

I have started working an organisation that uses ArcGIS to manage its GIS data generally.  They use a wide range of other software and methods to also manage collection of routine data, such as:

1. Water Meter readings - the meter locations are stored in GIS, but the usage data is stored elsewhere
2. Water quality sampling - there are a range of locations where the samples are collected weekly/monthly/quarterly for laboratory analysis and stored in an excel spreadsheet.

The current system is fragmented and I thought that ArcGIS could possibly manage this better by consolidating the data.  I am a novice in ArcGIS, but thought that possibly each "round" could be stored as a new feature, with geographic location linking results and the attribute table recording the specific round data (eg date, time, analysis results, etc).  In addition, I thought GIS system may enable capturing the spatial variation of results - for example areas of high water usage.

Is this a common use of ArcGIS?  I understand that ArcGIS can create "dashboards" and would this be a suitable delivery method?

Comment: What kind of spatial variation do you expect from water meter readings?  The meter locations shouldn't be varied.  Same with the water quality sampling - if there is a range of _specific_ locations for testing, these locations aren't changing either

Comment: Generally I dont expect location to change, but the readings over time to change.  There may also be some spatial trends in the data, for example certain areas are higher usage, or water quality in parts of the catchment may show some trend.  It is possible that the location could change gradually over time - for example meters removed and new ones added, same with sample points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use ESRI's Survey123 to collect meter reading data AND water quality monitoring data (amongst other things).

You will need either ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise to use Survey123.  Note that even with ArcGIS Online, it can be configured to store the survey results into your local enterprise geodatabase (instead of the default of storing in ArcGIS Online) if you run ArcGIS Server.  We use ArcGIS Online, and the survey results are submitted directly into our local geodatabase.  See:  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014793

I use a combination of ArcGIS Collector and Survey123 to make it easy for the users.  They find the meter (or monitoring point) in the Collector map and the map is configured so that in the meter's pop up details view, there is a "New Meter Read Survey" link.  Tapping on this link opens Meter Read survey in Survey123 with some of the meter data already filled in (using a Survey123 URL in the link in the collector map, with survey answers already embedded in the URL).  See:  https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/reference/integratewithotherapps.htm

This way, the survey results (meter reads) can be easily related (or joined) to the meter features in ArcGIS or using database views.

Works well for us, including in locations where no network is available (so long as the users have downloaded their map and survey before they left the network).

Sorry, I cannot comment on the dashboard idea.  We do not use that (although I have used a dashboard web app, but that was not suitable for this particular use case).